# Please define the term "Multi-byte safe"

Tags: utf-8

I'm a bit lost with UTF-8 right now.
I'm looking for a precise definition of the term multi-byte safe.

Comment: Bytes used to represent single-byte characters are always 7-bit, i.e. less than 128, and bytes used to represent multi-byte characters are always 8-bit, i.e. have the most significant bit on, i.e. greater than 127. So multi-byte safe for UTF-8 would be if the byte was less than 128. Other encodings may have a different maximum value for multi-byte safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are dealing with unicode characters, it is not safe to assume that all the characters just take a single byte or char (java). So when reading or parsing a string, you need to take this into consideration.

Here is an [excellent article](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_encodings) which explains complexities when dealing with Unicode w.r.t Java.

> 1. Stored characters can take up an inconsistent number of bytes. A UTF-8
>      encoded character might take between
>      one (LATIN_CAPITAL_LETTER_A) and four
>      (MATHEMATICAL_FRAKTUR_CAPITAL_G)
>      bytes. Variable width encoding has
>      implications for reading into and
>      decoding from byte arrays.
> 2. Not all code points can be stored in a char. The
>      MATHEMATICAL_FRAKTUR_CAPITAL_G example
>      lies in the supplementary range of
>      characters and cannot be stored in 16
>      bits. It must be represented by two
>      sequential char values, neither of
>      which is meaningful by itself. The
>      Character class provides methods for
>      working with 32-bit code points.

```
    // Unicode code point to char array
     char[] math_fraktur_cap_g = Character.toChars(0x1D50A);
```